# Ruby on Rails 4 Validation of Form Radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

I have a form with a radio button with four different selections.  I want to make sure that the user selects at lease one of the radio buttons prior to submitting the form.  Right now, I am doing this manually because I could not get the validation to work.  I would prefer to figure out a way to use the validation so this can be done client side before submitting the form.  Does anyone have experience with validation for radio buttons?

View:

```
<tr>
  <td width="30%" align="center" style="color:white;"><%= f.radio_button :file_type, "1" %>Type 1</td>
  <td width="25%" align="center" style="color:white;"><%= f.radio_button :file_type, "2" %>Type 2</td>
  <td width="20%" align="center" style="color:white;"><%= f.radio_button :file_type, "3" %>Type 3</td>
  <td width="25%" align="center" style="color:white;"><%= f.radio_button :file_type, "4" %>Type 4</td>
</tr>
```

In my Model, I tried the following code, but this didn't work:

```
validates :file_type, presence: true
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [validates_inclusion_of](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of) to validate `file_type` in your model:

```
validates_inclusion_of :file_type, :in => 1..4
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that the inclusion before too, but for some reason its as if it isn't ever getting to the model validation.  It goes directly to the controller and gives an error in the code.

Comment: How about this: `validates_inclusion_of :file_type, :in => %w(1 2 3 4)`? Can you please try this? and let me know.

Comment: Hi KM, I wasn't able to get it to work with that either.  There must be something else going on that is causing it to not validate properly, I tried your syntax in a dummy form and it works.  I'm not sure why it isn't working in this particular situation.